# Can pygame events be handled in select.select input list?

Tags: python, sockets, select, pygame, multiplayer

The documentation for python's [`select.select`](http://devdocs.io/python/library/select) says:

> Note that on Windows, it only works for sockets; on other operating
>   systems, it also works for other file types (in particular, on Unix,
>   it works on pipes).

My group is developing a simplistic multiplayer game using pygame and [sockets](http://devdocs.io/python/library/socket). (We **are not** using Twisted or zeromq or any similar libraries; this being the only constraint).

Now, for the game design; we want the player to send data to the server when a key event occurs in the pygame screen. The client/player side's socket will otherwise be hooked to server and listen for changes occurring on other players' side. For this task, I'd need the pygame and socket to work parallely. I was recommended to use `select` module from several users on #python.

Can I do something like:

```
inp = [self.sock, pygame.event.get]
out = [self.server]
i, o, x = select.select( inp, out, [] )
```

If not, what should be the way to go?

Comment: This won't work. `select.select` expects file descriptors (or integers representing them) or objects that return descriptors on a `fileno()` call. The `pygame.event.get` function does not do this. Why not just use a non-blocking socket?

Comment: @DominicKexel All the examples I see for non-blocking sockets are related to `select`. Could you link me to relevant articles?

Answer (score 2):

You could use threads for this task. Is it necessary to process server messages and pygame events in series (not concurrently)? If so, you could do this:

```
class SocketListener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sock, queue):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
         self.daemon = True
         self.socket = sock
         self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
         while True:
             msg = self.socket.recv()
             self.queue.put(msg)
class PygameHandler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
         self.queue = queue
         self.daemon = True
    def run(self):
         while True:
             self.queue.put(pygame.event.wait())
queue = Queue.Queue()
PygameHandler(queue).start()
SocketListener(queue).start()
while True:
    event = queue.get()
    """Process the event()"""
```

If not, you could process the events inside the run methods of the `PygameHandler` and `SocketListener` classes.